# Loading data into the google BigQuery from other than file sources(from another database)

Tags: database, google-bigquery

I have just started exploring the google BigQuery platform. I have created project, data-set and table.I have successfully loaded data to the table using csv as a source file.

Now I am exploring it's API.I would like to know, whether is there any way to load data using any database as a source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help you get started:

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/loading-data

Comment: Yep.I already have gone through this but failed to find anything related to my question.

Comment: wait. I think, I just found it. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery#streaminginsertexamples

Comment: Great. That link is is just a sub page from the link I posted in my answer. So please accept the answer.